# Deploy a .net web service to Jboss server

Tags: java, web-services, visual-studio-2012, jboss

I am trying to figure out how to deploy my WebService project to my running Jboss server. This seems to be a lot harder than it sounds. I can not find any tutorials or guides on how to do this.

I have tried to deploy the whole Web Service Application project as a .rar file via the administrator console but it gives an "unknown error". I am able to run the WebService on the developer webserver.

Is there any best practice or other lean way to deploy my webservice directly in Visual Studio?

I've also tried to publish the project through Visual Studio but the wizard says that localhost:8080 which is where my Jboss application server is running on, but it says that it doesnt exists.

Any suggestions on how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JBoss can only run applications that are compiled to JVM bytecode. A .NET application is using the CLR runtime, not the JVM.

Comment: Ofcourse.. I feel stupid now. But if I want to consume my webservice in a Java application I will need to publish my webservice to a web server. Do you have any recommendations on how to do this?

Comment: I am not familiar with the .NET eco-system, so I don't know what are the lightweight alternatives to using IIS to deploy your webservice.

Comment: I will go with the IIS for now then. Thanks for your answer!